# Citing different web pages by the same author in APA

Tags: citations

I have been looking through the APA handbook and I can't seem to find a binding advise on this.

I have a couple of web pages in my reference list by the same author (a company), all without a date:

```
Nederbooms. (n.d.). *CGN core corpus | Nederbooms*. Retrieved on April 13, 2014,
     from http://nederbooms.ccl.kuleuven.be/eng/cgntb
Nederbooms. (n.d.). *Lassy small | Nederbooms*. Retrieved on April 13, 2014,
     from http://nederbooms.ccl.kuleuven.be/eng/lassytb
```

The problem is referring to these sources inline. How would I go about doing so? Let's say I refer to the first source. This is how I would do it - but I can't be sure.

> Most bananas are yellow, but some are green and some are even brown
>   (Nederbooms, n.d., "CGN core corpus").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that in APA style the author and year are used in the in text citation keys and these keys need to be unambiguous. When you have the same authors, in the same order, and the same date of publication, you add a letter to the publication date. You do the same thing even when the publication date is unknown. According to the [APA blog](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/01/alphabetizing-in-press-and-no-date-references.html)

> Also remember that if you have two or more “in press” or “no date”
>   references with the same authors in the same order, you should use
>   lowercase letters—a, b, c, and so forth ... The only difference between these types of references and references with publication years is that “in press” and “no date” references contain a hyphen before the a, b, and so forth:
>
> American Speech-Language-Hearing Association. (n.d.-a). The knowledge ...
>
> American Speech-Language-Hearing Association. (n.d.-b). A strategy to ...
>
> Schafer, G., & Plunkett, K. (2011a). The power ...
>
> Schafer, G., & Plunkett, K. (2011b). Task complexity ...
>
> Schafer, G., & Plunkett, K. (in press-a). The rapid learning ...
>
> Schafer, G., & Plunkett, K. (in press-b). Sometimes a child ...

Comment: This would result in an inline citation such as `Most bananas are yellow, but some are green and some are even brown (Nederbooms, n.d.-a).` Correct?

Comment: @BramVanroy that is my interpretation of the style guide.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had never seen the usage of a letter following `no date`. Thank you for the clarification.